# ubuntu port forwarding problem

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I've installed and already configured php5, mysql server & client and apache 2 on my server ubuntu (vmware). also I've installed vsftpd. when i type `ifconfig` it shows server IP and client (windows) can show it with both http and ftp, but in local network, where people are connected wirelessly, i cannot show them my IP. what is the problem, i googled but with no results, the only think i saw is `PORT FORWARDING`, but how? how can i fix it and show them my IP, I'm newbie in linux, i know ubuntu is easier and if you can help me, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your ubuntu is running on a virtual machine inside a Windows host - in this case, you need to configure your Windows machine to forward all requests it gets on ports 20 and 21 (tcp) to the IP address of the virtual machine in order to have it visible for other computers on your lan.

Use some sort of port forwarding app for windows (such as this one here, but there are many others: http://www.rouvali.com/index.php?id=53) and configure forwarding of ports 20 and 21 to the IP of the virtual machine. The other computers will have to connect to the IP of your Windows machine (type **ipconfig** in a command prompt to see it) in order to reach the ubuntu VM.

Comment: it would probably quicker and easier to set the VM to bridging mode, then the vm has an IP on the network, no forwarding required